# Error while publishing the web application

Tags: asp.net

I am a fresher in `vs 2010` and developed a web project.
When I hosted directly the project its working fine.
When I am trying to publish it not working and giving an error **403**

```
Error   1   Web deployment task failed.
(The metabase path 'http://localhost/webapp/login.aspx' is not supported. 
Paths must be of the format '/lm/w3svc/<siteid>/ROOT/...'.)

The metabase path 'http://localhost/webapp/login.aspx' is not supported. 
Paths must be of the format '/lm/w3svc/<siteid>/ROOT/...'.
The metabase key '/lm/w3svc/1964704031' could not be found.
The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)     0   0   WebApplication1
```

I referred  many sites and didn't get any solution for this problem
Please anyone help me to solve this issue.
My `OS` is windows server 2003 `iis 6`.

I have given the
**Publish method:WebDeploy
service url:http://localhost/webapp
Site/application:http://localhost/webapp/login.aspx**
Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `iis` is running on the same network as your development environment, then just use `File System`, and publish to the root folder where the website is hosted from.

Answer (score 5):

Site/application must be your SiteName/YourAppFolder for example like 
Default Web Site/webapp

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer sir.It worked for me.The folder that is present in wwwroot should be copied and that folder should be installed in client machine  IIS using a virtual directory...Is this the way to do... Am I correct please reply me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your are very welcome. I am not quite sure what you mean by "copying" the folder but the normal workflow would be:
1. In IIS Manager right click your Web Site and choose New... and then Virtual Directory. This Virtual Directory should map to a physical path for example wwwroot\mywebapp.
2. You might need to configure your Virtual Directory in order to allow your Application to run (Rad/Write Acces, ISAPI Filters etc.) You will see this options while creating the Virtual Directory, just choose what is right for you.
3. Deploy your Web application from Visual Studio

hope this helps.